# json-framework: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on stringWithObject

Tags: objective-c, json, json-framework

---

UPDATE:

I found that the reason for the previous error was an error in the documentation.

The method should be named proxyForJson, not jsonProxyObject...

But I'm still stuck, though.

I now get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error inside stringWithObject some where. Any clues?

---

UPDATE 2:

My proxyForJson implementation is a cut-n-paste from then documentation:

```
- (id)proxyForJson {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            Navn, @"Navn",
            Adresse, @"Adresse",
            Alder, @"Alder",
            nil];
}
```

---

Trying to make json serialization work for my custom objective-c class.

As I understand the documentation, json-framework can serialize custom objects, if they implement the [jsonProxyObject](http://json-framework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/interfaceNSObject_07SBProxyForJson_08.html) method.

So I have this class:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    NSString *Name;
    NSString *Addresse;
    NSInteger Age;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Addresse;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger Age;
- (id)jsonProxyObject;
@end
```

And I try to serialize an array with some instances in it:

```
[json stringWithObject:list error:&error];
```

But all I get is he following error:

"JSON serialisation not supported for MyObject"

I guess the jsonWriter can't find my jsonProxyObject method for some reason, buy why?

Regards.

Comment: Could you show your implementation of proxyForJason?

Comment: Of course I will. Added to the question right now.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, please can you share the solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I left the problem unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to turn on NSZombies and MallocStackLogging in your Executable Info pane to check the source of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS? If not, you might try this and check the console for the output.
EXC_BAD_ACCESS is often an error caused by over-releasing an object somewhere.

Comment: MallocStackLogging gives the following lines in the console:  
Json testing(22492) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
Json testing(22492) malloc: process 22451 no longer exists, stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.22451.Json testing.ms0Jvs.index
Json testing(22492) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.22492.Json testing.JhgUjE.index

Cant get anything useful out of the stack-logs..

NSZombies doesn't seem to do any difference.

Comment: Hm... I am not sure about how you used the malloc_history option. Try to run the App in debug mode, wait until it stops (the error occurs) - don't terminate the app, since it will terminate the process henceforth, open the Terminal end enter: malloc_history PID MA, were PID is the process ID and MA the memory adress (like 0xa4e10). Pretty much the last object mentioned there should have caused the trouble.

Comment: I added MallocStackLogging = YES to environment options.
Typing malloc_history in the terminal doesn't give me much either. Not sure I have the right PID and addr, though. Used the PID that I found in activity monitor (for Json testing, not for simulator bridge). For the addr, I used a value found in the debuggers title: 'asm CFRetain 0x01b75900: json testing - Debugger'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the right thing to do but defining the class as follows, solves the problem:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    NSString *Name;
    NSString *Addresse;
    NSInteger *Age;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Addresse;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger *Age;

- (id)jsonProxyObject;

@end
```

Then initializing the variable as:

```
Age = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:32];
```

Answer (score 0):

In NSString, there is no `stringWithObject:` method. You should try using `stringWithFormat:` instead.